# Load a form and submit the same form with username and password by using a script or curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to load a form and submit the same form with username and password by using a script or curl.

This is because the `default_csrf_cookie_name` will be created when the form is loaded.

The form is load from another site by clicking a link.

After the form is loaded, is it possible to enter username and password using a script/curl and submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields = array(
        'uname' => $val,
        'pass' => $pass,
        // form data as key => val format
    );

    $fields_string = "";

    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

and use

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

Comment: Thanks. But before I can post the data, I need to get the csrf_cookie_name from the target url, as csrf_cookie_name is part of the $fields_string  
And after the post, how to redirect to that target URL?

Comment: Are yyou familiar with zend framework ?? If yes then you can try using       $client = new Zend_HTTP_Client(); and then setCookieJar() method wich stores all cookies..this might be helpful to you.